# Python: how to insert a series of data into database and display them all

Tags: python, database

i am try to using python with database to display a series of information.
however, my output only display the last column.
i know i am not express my means very clearly. 
so, i put my code and output as follow:
now the output show:

```
 $ python pricewatch.py
Harvey Norman Site Search
iPad 2 Wi-Fi 16GB Black
iPad 2 Wi-Fi 16GB
iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular 32GB
iPad mini Wi-Fi 16GB
iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular 64GB
iPad Wi-Fi 64GB with Retina Display
iPad Wi-Fi 32GB with Retina Display
iPad 2 Wi-Fi 16GB White
iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G 16GB
iPad Wi-Fi + Cellular 32GB with Retina Display
iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular 16GB
$357
$697
$756
$647
$395
$545
$777
$487
(8, u'iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular 16GB', u'Harvey Norman Site Search', u'$487')
```

//as you can see, it only show the last one 
my code is

```
url="http://m.harveynorman.com.au/computers/tablets-readers/ipads"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

sitename=soup.find('label',{'for':'search'})
print sitename.renderContents()

productname=soup.findAll('strong',{'class':'name fn'})
for eachproductname in productname:

    print  eachproductname.renderContents()

productprice=soup.findAll('span',{'class':'price'})
for eachproductprice in productprice:

  print eachproductprice.renderContents().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>","")

conn =sqlite3.connect('pricewatch.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists table1 (id integer, name text, store text, price real)")
eachname = eachproductname.renderContents()
eachprice = eachproductprice.renderContents().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>","")
sitename = sitename.renderContents()
assignnumber = randint(1,30) #issue here,want to assign a series of number by the scriptself
data = [(assignnumber,eachname,sitename,eachprice),
        ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (?,?,?,?)',data)

#output
for row in c.execute('select * from table1'):
       print row
```

now, the output i want from the database is like
(1,ipadXX,HN,$199)
(2,ipad xx, NH, $200)
.....

hope anyone can give the hints or edit my script.

regards
yuhang

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with:

```
for row in c.execute('select * from table1'):
   print row
```

Just make sure you commit the inserts first:

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (?,?,?,?)',data)
conn.commit()
```

Then you can still pull the records one by one instead of retrieving all rows at once as with `fetchall()`.

Comment: Hi,i also tried the conn.commit()before, it only repeat the column again and again. not work,thanks ~

Comment: Hi,the data i identified is scrape form the website as above script. what you mean "data isn't what i think it is?"~thanks

Comment: See Chris' answer... You've only inserting a single row to the database

Comment: @JonClements: See [what you have done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863991/how-to-delete-the-u-and-before-the-of-database-table-display-by-python) by not formatting the rows? :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters yup - all my fault obviously ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should call `fetchall` after `execute`:

```
for row in c.execute("select * from table1").fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

@jon Clements is right, your problem is here:

```
data = [(assignnumber,eachname,sitename,eachprice),
    ]
```

that needs to be in a loop -- right now it's only being assigned the first set of values, and that is all that is being inserted.

EDIT

Okay, so you want something like this:

```
for (name, price) in zip(productname, productprice):
  name_data = name.renderContents()
  price_data = price.renderContents().replace() # fill in your replacements here
  site_data = sitename.renderContents()
  assign_number = random.randint(1,30)

  c.execute('insert into table1 values (?,?,?,?)', 
            (name_data, price_data, site_data, assign_name))
```

Comment: hi, i tired to add a loop, i used the while. however, i am not sure how to loop in this case. i tired to loop the row times,the output shows nothing; then i tired to loop the data, the output shows syntaxerror. so could you please give more detail hints for the loop