# how to delete the "u and ' ' " before the of database table display by python

Tags: python, database

I am trying to use python to create a database and then insert data and display it.
However, the output adds a `u` before every string.
What should I do, how can I delete the "u"?
the following is the output display:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Date         | Time    | Price      |
-----------------------------------------------
(u'31/05/2013', u'11:10', u'$487')
(u'31/05/2013', u'11:11', u'$487')
(u'31/05/2013', u'11:13', u'$487')
(u'31/05/2013', u'11:19', u'$487')
```

I want the output only shows like

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Date         | Time    | Price      |
-----------------------------------------------
 31/05/2013       11:10     $487
```

I do not want to see the `u` and the `''`.

the following is a part of my code

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists table2 (date text, time text, price real)")

date=strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
time=strftime("%H:%M")
data1 = [(date,time,eachprice),
        ]
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (?,?,?)', data1)
conn.commit()
#output
print "Showing history for 'ipad mini', from harveynorman"
print "-----------------------------------------------"
print "| Date         | Time    | Price      |"
print "-----------------------------------------------"
for row in cursor.execute('select * from table2').fetchall():
       print row
```

so, could anyone can help me figure out how to delete the `g` and `''`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at whole tuples with unicode strings; the `u''` is normal when showing you a tuple with unicode values inside:

```
>>> print u'Hello World!'
Hello World!
>>> print (u'Hello World',)
(u'Hello World',)
```

You want to format each row:

```
print u' {:<15} {:<8} {:<6}'.format(*row)
```

See the [`str.format()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), specifically the [Format Syntax reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings); the above formats 3 values with field widths, left-aligning each value into their assigned width.

The widths are approximate (I didn't count the number of spaces in your post exactly), but should be easy to adjust to fit your needs.

Demo:

```
>>> row = (u'31/05/2013', u'11:10', u'$487')
>>> print u' {:<15} {:<8} {:<6}'.format(*row)
 31/05/2013      11:10    $487
```

or, using a loop and a sequence of row entries:

```
>>> rows = [
... (u'31/05/2013', u'11:10', u'$487'),
... (u'31/05/2013', u'11:11', u'$487'),
... (u'31/05/2013', u'11:13', u'$487'),
... (u'31/05/2013', u'11:19', u'$487'),
... ]
>>> for row in rows:
...     print u' {:<15} {:<8} {:<6}'.format(*row)
... 
 31/05/2013      11:10    $487  
 31/05/2013      11:11    $487  
 31/05/2013      11:13    $487  
 31/05/2013      11:19    $487
```

Comment: @MartijinPieters thanks a lot, real helpful, i am planing read the links first because i still have many tables need to display.